# tailwindcss group-hover not working on transforms

Tags: tailwind-css

Is it possible to use transforms with the group-hover pseudo selector? I can get group-hover to work for things that aren't transforms like text color, but I can't get it to work while doing things like translate-x or scale. Below is an example. Neither of the group-hover transforms on the inner div work for me but the group hover for background and text work.

```
<div class="group">
  <div id="inner" class="transform group-hover:translate-x-1/2 group-hover:scale-110 group-hover:bg-blue-200">
       <p class="group-hover:text-white">some text</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong? [here's a codepen of it in action](https://codepen.io/corduroy/pen/mdRqxVb)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See, as per the [documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover) `group-hover` is enabled for a few core plugins which does not include `transform`.

So to support `transform` too, you will have to enable `group-hover` variant for it in the `tailwind.config.js`, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you seemed to miss that even though it's very clear lol

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted. So that it is useful for others too :)

Comment: how to enable it can you add the code

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover) is not that detailed.

To make `group-hover` work with `transform` -> `translate` you have to enable it in fact for the `translate` attribute - not `transform`.
At least this is what worked for me in tailwind v2.2.16.

You can do it like this (so it will work both for `group-hover` and `hover`):

```
  config: {
    variants: {
      extend: {
        translate: ['group-hover', 'hover'],
      },
    },
  }
```

in your `tailwind.config.js` file.